# A specific layout using float

Tags: html, css

Ii's been a while since I programmed a website and it seems that I have forgot some basic concepts about FLOAT!

[image: How to make this layout in divs using FLOAT]

Can anyone help making this (on picture) layout using 4 divs and FLOAT?

I have tried this:

```
    <header>
            <div id="fill_left"></div>
            <div id="top"></div>
            <div id="fill_right"></div>
            <div id="bottom"></div>  
    </header>
```

And CSS:

```
header {
width: 100%;
height: 9em;
background-color: lightblue;
}

#fill_left{
width: 5%;
height: 100%;
background-color: lightcoral;
float: left;
}

#top{
width:80%;
height: 50%;
background-color: lightgray;
float: left;
}
#bottom{
width:80%;
height: 50%;
background-color: lightseagreen;
float: left;
}

#fill_right{
width: 5%;
height: 100%;
background-color: lightcoral;
float: left;
}
```

And of course they're all inside a wrapper{ width: 100%, height: 138px}

Thanks

Comment: Show us your HTML and a screenshot and we can help you debug.

Comment: How about [this solution of mine](http://jsbin.com/waqipe/1/edit) with `display: table`?

Comment: How does 80 + 5 + 5 === 100% ?

Comment: right and left could be borders or background of a main wrapper , what are those actually ? some text inside, a plain color, an image, horrible adverts ? ..... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by using an extra div to warp `div-2` and `div-3` by set `float: left;`

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6mxbadLk/) or [Full Screen View](http://jsfiddle.net/6mxbadLk/show/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div-p">
    <div id="div-1"></div>
    <div id="div-c">
        <div id="div-2"></div>
        <div id="div-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="div-4"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
#div-p {
    width: 100%;
    height: 138px;
}
#div-c {
    width: 90%;
    height: 138px;
    float: left;
}
#div-1 {
    width: 5%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
#div-2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: green;
}
#div-3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: blue;
}
#div-4 {
    width: 5%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
}
```

**Solution 2:**

You could also do it by using `display: inline-block;` and set `font-size:0px;` to `#div-p` for remove the white-space and then set `font-size: 16px;` (i.e 16px = 1em) to child elements.

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6mxbadLk/3/) or [Full Screen View](http://jsfiddle.net/6mxbadLk/3/show/)**

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
#div-p {
    width: 100%;
    height: 138px;
    font-size: 0px;
}
#div-c {
    width: 90%;
    height: 138px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#div-1 {
    width: 5%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#div-2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: green;
}
#div-3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: blue;
}
#div-4 {
    width: 5%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: As simple as that! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

That simple Notice the order: http://jsbin.com/liqulo/1/edit

```
  <div id="fill_left"></div>
  <div id="fill_right"></div>    

  <div id="top"></div>
  <div id="bottom"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#fill_left,
#fill_right{
  width: 5%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
#fill_left{  float: left;  }
#fill_right{ float: right; }   /* and notice Float Right */
```

---

But if I were you I would do it **even simpler**: http://jsbin.com/liqulo/2/edit

```
<header>       
  <div class="cont" id="top"></div>
  <div class="cont" id="bottom"></div>
</header>
```

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 9em;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
.cont{
  width:90%;
  height: 50%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```